# How can I output the longest login time in minutes (not hh:mm)?

Tags: bash, awk

I cannot cut out from the 10th argument which looks like this: (01:53) the hours and minutes.
My code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! $# -eq 1 ] #we need only one username
then echo usage: $0 Error!
     exit 1
fi

if [ $(finger $1 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -c "no such user") -gt 0 ]
then    echo #this is a nonexistent username
        echo No such username
else    #existent username
        us=$1;
        last $1 | awk 'BEGIN {time=$10 }
                         ($10 > x) && ($10 != "in") {
                                time = $10
                         } 
                        END{
                        print "Longest login time:" time  }'
fi
```

Output:

```
(01:53)
```

I need:

```
113
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
time="01:53"
IFS=: read hours minutes <<<"$time"
time_in_mins=$(( 60 * 10#$hours + 10#$minutes ))
echo "$time_in_mins"
```

I'm explicitly using base 10 for the variables, so that `08` and `09` are not interpreted as invalid octal numbers

---

`grep -q` is a good option for `if` conditions: instead of

```
if [ $(finger $1 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -c "no such user") -gt 0 ]
```

use this

```
if finger $1 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -q "no such user"
```

---

Taking a closer look at what you're doing, I'd do the calculations in the awk command: Note that the time output from `last` can include days.

```
  last "$1" | awk -F '[()]' '
      function to_minutes(time,    d, a, n) {
          n = split(time, a, /\+/)
          if (n == 2) {
              d = a[1]
              time = a[2]
          }
          n = split(time, a, /:/)
          return (1440*d + 60*a[1] + a[2])
      }
      {
          time = to_minutes($2 ? $2 : 0)
          max = time > max ? time : max
      }
      END {print max}
  '
```